# On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?

Tags: filenames, history, portability, slash

Throughout the POSIX specification, there's provision ([1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267), [2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12), [3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/utilities/dirname.html)...) to allow implementations to treat a path starting with two `/` specially.

A POSIX application (an application written to the POSIX specification to be portable to all POSIX compliant systems) cannot assume that `//foo/bar` is the same as `/foo/bar` (though they can assume that `///foo/bar` is the same as `/foo/bar`).

Now what are those POSIX systems (historical and still maintained) that treat `//foo` specially? I believed (I've now [been proven wrong](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11947/focus=11965)) that POSIX provision was pushed by Microsoft for their Unix variant (XENIX) and possibly Windows POSIX layer (can anyone confirm that?).

It is used by Cygwin which also is a POSIX-like layer for Microsoft Windows. Are there any non-Microsoft Windows systems? OpenVMS?

On systems where `//foo/bar` is special, what is it used for? `//host/path` for network file systems access? Virtual file systems?

Do some *applications* running on Unix-likes —if not the system's API— treat `//foo/bar` paths specially (in contexts where they otherwise treat `/foo/bar` as the path on the filesystem)?

---

**Edit**, I've since [asked a question on the austin-group mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11947) about the origin of `//foo/bar` handling in the spec, and the discussion is an interesting read (from an archaeology point of view at least).

Comment: Related: [Official Description UNC (Universal Naming Convention)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57428)

Comment: already, `ls -ld //` displays `d.....  //` instead of `d..... /` : is it one of the side effect you are looking for ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, No. `ls -ld ///` would also display `///`, `ls` just displays the file it is being told to display as it was given. I'm looking for systems or applications that treat //foo/var specially (not as a path on the filesystem) like Cygwin does.

Comment: on my Linux box, `/boot/grub` and `//boot/grub` and `///boot/grub` and `//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////boot/grub` are all the same according to a range of applications.

Comment: standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) says, as you mentionned, "A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner" (more than 2 resolves to 1 /). An exemple found on the net : http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=83 ( `IBM's z/OS resolves //pathname requests to MVS datasets (as opposed to the hierarchical filesystem (HFS)) (......) Additionally, z/OS would not accept or recognize additional "directory" or "file" components appended to such paths.`... not exactly unix, though ^^).

Comment: I don't know about POSIX, but on the AmigaOS, `cd /` (or just `/`) is what `cd ..` is for Unix. So AmigaOS would interpret `/foo/bar` as Unix would `cd ../foo/bar`, and `//foo/bar` as Unix would `cd ../../foo/bar`. (The filesystem root would be `:`.)

Comment: @DevSolar: really interresting (and surprising), but we should stick to POSIX only, as out of POSIX **anything** is possible ^^

Comment: On Windows a path starting with `\\` is a UNC path, but Windows doesn't follow POSIX (nor claim to).

Comment: if `///foo/bar` is the same as `/foo/bar` then why on Linux, chromium would open a image file as `file:///home/edward/Pictures/arch-wallpaper.png` ? (note the starting three slashes)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds because the first bit is the URL: `file://`, alike to `http://` and such. On chrome here at work a windows UNC path that I have open now is `file:////$MACHINE/$SHARENAME/index.html` (although for some reason it also understands `file://$MACHINE/...`)

Comment: related [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469921/what-is-the-significance-of-in-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469921/what-is-the-significance-of-in-bash)

Comment: As I remember, on Solaris `//foo` meant accessing some form of remote filestore, global to the network.

Answer (score 103):

This is a compilation and index of the answers given so far. This post is *community wiki*, it can be edited by anybody with 100+ reputation and nobody gets reputation from it. Feel free to post your own answer and add a link to it in here (or wait for me to do it). Ideally, this answer should just be a summary (with short entries while individual other answers would have the details).

#### Currently actively maintained systems:

- [**Cygwin**](https://cygwin.com/). A POSIX layer for Microsoft Windows. [Used for Windows UNC paths](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths).
- [**UWIN**](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix-nt97/full_papers/korn/korn.pdf) since 1.3. Another POSIX layer for Windows. Used at least for `//host/file` network file sharing paths.
- <sup>[@OlivierDulac](/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar?noredirect=1#comment443337_256497)</sup> **IBM z/OS** as [mentioned in the POSIX bug tracker](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=83#c191), *z/OS resolves `//pathname` requests to MVS datasets*, not to network files. [Example](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa400/cpsdsuf.htm%23cpsdsuf).

#### Defunct systems

- <sup>[@BinaryZebra](/a/256532)</sup> [**Apollo Domain/OS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/OS) (confirmed). Also mentioned at [Official Description UNC (Universal Naming Convention)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57428) as the possible [origin of `//host/path` notations](http://www.typewritten.org/Articles/Apollo/005488-02.pdf) ([see also](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/apollo/014962-A00_Domain_OS_Design_Principles_Jan89.pdf), page 2-15).

  According to [Donn Terry](https://www.linkedin.com/in/donnterry), it was HP (which acquired Apollo Computers) that [pushed for inclusion of that provision in the POSIX spec](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11965) for Domain/OS.
- <sup>[@jillagre](/a/256517)</sup> **Tektronix Utek** ([corroborated](//groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/fwoIkec839AJ)), where `//host/path` is a path on a *distributed file system*.
- <sup>[@gilles](/a/421082)</sup> **[QNX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNX) 4** with the FLEET distributed processing system, where `//123/path` is a `/path` on node 123. (Mentioned [in the QNX 6 documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_user_guide%2Ffiles.html&cp=13_11_6_1&anchor=PATHNAMES).)
- <sup>[@roaima](/a/256526/22565)</sup> **AT&T SysV Release 3** (unverified). `//host/path` in (discontinued in SVR4) [RFS Remote File Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Sharing) system.
- <sup>[@Scott](/a/256612)</sup> **SEL/Gould UTX-32** (unverified). Used for `//host/path`.

#### Applications that treat `//foo/bar` specially for paths

- <sup>[@Prem](/a/256513)</sup> **Perforce** where `//depot/A/B/C/D` refers to a path in a *depot*.
- <sup>[@WChargin](/a/256633)</sup> **[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)**. In its configuration [you use a `//` prefix for *relative paths* (to the blend associated with the data-block)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/relative_paths.html).
- The **[Bazel](https://bazel.build/)** build system uses a `//` prefix for [labels of targets within the Bazel build graph](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/build-ref.html#labels).

Comment: Using the `//` namespace was proposed by some Linux kernel developers for Reiser4's metadata facilities, but I don't think this proposal ever gained traction within Namesys, nor was it ever implemented.

Comment: Windows itself implements the POSIX API... how does that handle a leading double slash?

Comment: We can add that on the web, resources starting with a double slash define a different root than the single slash does.

Comment: @Kevin, yes I also believe it (see the question), though I think it was an optional component and only on some variants of Windows and now discontinued. If you have more details, please add an answer.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier. Yes, you'll notice [it's actually used in this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/256569/edit) ;-).

Comment: Is UWIN really "actively maintained"?  Where?

Comment: @jrw32982, it's true the [future of uwin like that of `ksh93`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246338) is uncertain, but it may be a bit premature to call them dead yet.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, samba accepts `//foo/bar` specifications for CIFS shares, not as file paths, not in contexts where it also accepts normal paths. There's a deleted answer that mentioned the same for `mount -t cifs` (which does invoke some samba utility).

Comment: @Gilles, I've rolled back your emacs  edit as the Q&A is about where file paths that _start_       with `//` receive a special treatment as allowed by POSIX.

Comment: @Kevin Windows has supported / as alternative to \ for a long time (I have no idea how long, but must've been many many years now), which includes UNC paths and their \\ (or //, respectively) prefix, which fits conveniently with the POSIX spec. Under `cmd.exe` a path including `/`s needs to be enclosed in double quotes to prevent interception and interpretation as switches, but otherwise `dir "//foo/bar"` et al work fine.

Answer (score 16):

> Do some applications running on Unix-likes —if not the system's API— treat //foo/bar Paths specially?

I am aware of Perforce which uses `//depot/A/B/C/D` Paths to refer to the Depot.
Perforce also supports `//Client/C/D` Paths, when the Client is pointing to `//depot/A/B/`. Here, local FileSystem may not have these Paths.

`p4 filelog //depot/A/B/C/D` will show the history of that file, even though there is no file `/depot/A/B/C/D`.

`p4 filelog C/D` will also show the history of that file, if executed from appropriate Directory.

Reference : https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.fspecs.html

Answer (score 13):

Several decades ago, [Tektronix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tektronix#.27Non_test.27_products) Utek (BSD 4.2 based Unix, first on National Semiconductors [32016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS320xx) CPUs then Motorola [68020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68020)s) was providing something called DFS (distributed file system) under which `//foo/bar` was referring to the `/bar` file on the `foo` dfs server. It was later obsoleted by Sun's NFS.

Unfortunately, I haven't reference yet to back that but I might eventually find some Utek documentation in my cellar and update this reply.

Comment: Corroborated by [this usenet discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/odYmusRRREQJ)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I believe that this [link to Usenet discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/nv4Q_ot2feYJ#!msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/nv4Q_ot2feYJ) is better. The one you choose has Domain/OS but not Utek. Or [the next message](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/fwoIkec839AJ#!msg/comp.unix.questions/HtngJyl_TDI/fwoIkec839AJ) (from yours)

Comment: [from the author (working at Tektronix) of the public domain RFS implementation that made it to BSDs](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix-wizards/wSthNQfC-8o/kqOR6h3KOQsJ), there were both a DFS and RFS developed there.

Comment: [Tektronix/BSD RFS implementations apparently mounted remote file systems on regular files](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix-wizards/QwRVsZS9jEM/V4ZI64CKopsJ) to avoid `find` for instance traverse the mount point. The author explicitly  rules-out `//foo/bar` (or the Newcastle connection's `/../foo/bar`) there

Comment: [other usenet thread that confirms DFS](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.wizards/4_tcr8ClkMs/0L5XuoyBTXYJ)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane for these links. As I initially thought, that was indeed on Utek and not Utek V, and DFS was the file system name.

Answer (score 8):

Following the lead [from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/389345/353322). And reading page 2-15 from [the manual from Bitsavers](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/apollo/014962-A00_Domain_OS_Design_Principles_Jan89.pdf) (thanks <sup>[@grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)</sup>).

> Shared Data
>   The second design principle of the Domain/OS distributed file system, sharing by default, implies a global uniform name space. The name space of the distributed file system appears to users like that of a giant timesharing file system. It is a traditional UNIX hierarchical name space, except that absolute pathnames can begin with the name of the network root (called //). It is also possible to express pathnames relative to the root of the local node (the / directory).

There is also [an older manual from](http://www.typewritten.org/Articles/Apollo/005488-02.pdf)  with a "First Printing: July, 1985". On page 1-4:

> The double slashes (//) in Figure 1-2 represent the top level of the
>   naming tree, the network root directory.

So, we have confirmation that Domain/OS from Apollo used `//` for network root.

Comment: I think the grawity guy is a major [arch Linux dev](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=grawity&SeB=m).

Answer (score 5):

The [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org) project - which is a free and open-source implementation of the NT kernel and related APIs - has apparently undertaken to also implement its own [Interix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix)-like POSIX subsystem *(though MS's original OS/2 subsystem is also [mentioned in context](https://www.reactos.org/wiki/POSIX_Subsystem), no mention is made of a ReactOS analog)*.

Though the efforts so far have been [small](https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Psxss.exe), `fork()` is apparently a reality. Here is a an excerpt from the subsystem's project page, as listed under *open issues*:

> **paths**
>
> > What's the best way to use Win32 paths in POSIX applications? ideas:
> >
> > - translate `//<device>/<path`> into `\\.\<device>\<path>` *(with a special case for drive letters - `//<letter>/<path>` => `<letter>:\<path>` - and the special escape `//./<raw text>` => `\\.\<raw text>`. UNC paths can be specified with `//unc/<path>`)*. `//` paths are reserved by the standard for implementation-specific behavior, and the `//<letter>/` syntax to escape Win32 paths is widely used in existing POSIX compatibility environments
> > - heuristics to recognize "bare" Win32 paths as such
> > - case-insensitive lookup for Win32 paths and `//` paths *(does the standard allow this kind of implementation-specific behavior for `//` paths?)*.

I'm not sure how that qualifies as I am not sure how much of it has been implemented, but I thought it was a usefully interesting description of the problem.

Comment: XENIX didn't have a _POSIX subsystem_, Windows had AFAIK. XENIX was a Unix (initially based on Unix V7 which Microsoft bought a license of from AT&T).

Comment: Nice read [here](http://brianreiter.org/2010/08/24/the-sad-history-of-the-microsoft-posix-subsystem/) as well about interix/Windows POSIX subsystem

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - quite. I almost want to replace my link with it, but it is a little opinion-based at the end, and doesn't really work as a reference... but don't delete the comment, please?

Comment: In any case, it doesn't mention `//foo/bar` handling. I've not found strong evidence the Windows POSIX subsystem or Interix actually handled them so far.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I dunno if it was just extremely incosistent, or if leaving out the *optionally* part was just an oversight, but the MKS [`lsacl`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/lsacl.1.asp) command is spec'd to understand `\\machinename\driveletter:\path` while its [`registry`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/registry.1.asp) command was spec'd to understand that form or *optionally `//`* either way. As the MKS kit was the predecessor to Interix and was what MS shipped for versions 1/2 I would think Interix must have accepted compatible syntax for such a basic thing.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - and there is: ***[Do MKS Toolkit porting products support `pipe()`? What are named pipes?](https://www.mkssoftware.com/support/kb/faqs.asp?product=Toolkit&type=tech#art109)**
Yes, MKS Toolkit porting products support `pipe()`.
Win32 defines a named pipe, which is entirely different from a UNIX FIFO. Win32 named pipes let multiple clients establish bidirectional communications to a single server application, each with its own pair of buffers. The clients and server can be on different machines. You can access Win32 named pipes with `open("//server/pipe/<pipe name>")`.*

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - according to [this](https://www.mkssoftware.com/support/kb/default.asp?article=180) the lack of a mention of `//` for `lsacl` must have been just an oversight.

Answer (score 5):

Another application: [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) treats a leading `//` as a reference to the project directory (the directory in which the `.blend` file is saved). [Here's the relevant manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/open_save.html#relative-paths).

This is true for non-Unix-like operating systems (i.e., Windows) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have a vague memory that the `//host/path` notation was used on AT&T SysV.3 as part of its [RFS Remote File Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Sharing) implementation. This was eventually abandoned around the time SysV.4 was released in favour of the simpler but more popular [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) from Sun Microsystems.

However, I cannot find any concrete references to the syntax, and the documentation I have reviewed just now seems to indicate that the idea of the user explicitly specifying a remote hostname would have been opposed to the design principle of location independence.

References
1. [RFS Architectural overview](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pvMOQWt73JsC&lpg=PA92&ots=lxar3z4xR8&dq=SVR3%20file%20server%20rfs&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Founf [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pvMOQWt73JsC&lpg=PA92&ots=lxar3z4xR8&dq=SVR3%20file%20server%20rfs&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q&f=false) about RFS. I can't find references to `//host/path`. It seems to imply that network file systems have to be mounted explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. This is one of the pieces of "documentation I have reviewed", so I'll add a link to it if you don't mind. I'm still puzzling over this; it may come to me in the next day or so.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1980s, [SEL/Gould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Engineering_Laboratories) had a Unix operating system called UTX-32
in which `//host/path` was equivalent to
`/net/host/path` in Solaris;
i.e., remotely access path *`path`* on host *`host`*. 
I can't find any documentation on it,
so I don't know whether this was RFS or parallel evolution
(or whether AT&T <del>stole</del> acquired it from Gould).

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to have any reference on that (`//host/path` in UTX-32), by any chance?

Comment: It's possible that I have a hard-copy document in a box in my attic, but unlikely — (1) I don't recall *ever* having a lot of documentation (I remember a five-minute oral briefing); (2) even if I had it, I might not have taken it home; (3) even if I took it home, I probably threw it out some time in the past 30 years; and (4) even if I still have it, I probably won't be able to find it. Oh, also (0) I spent five minutes Googling it (to no avail) before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX states in the [*Rationale* for A.4.12 Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_12) Paragraphs 9 and 10:

> In some networked systems the construction /../hostname/ is used to refer to the root directory of another host, and POSIX.1 permits this behavior.
>
> Other networked systems use the construct //hostname for the same purpose; that is, a double initial slash is used.

This **seems** to confirm that `//` means "network root", or at least that that was the idea when the rule was included in POSIX.

---

Rules follow to remove any meaning of `//` in the middle of a path for an `/` started Pathname:

> ... since non-leading sequences of two or more <slash> characters
>   are treated as a single <slash>, ...

Of course, a `//` started Pathname may expand or change the use of `//` inside a Pathname (not at the start). POSIX.1 allows this.
This last confirms that the only `//` allowed are at the beginning of a Pathname.

Comment: I don’t understand the last paragraph. It seems to be saying that ``//foo/bar`` can be different from ``//foo//bar``. Is that what it means? Is there any reference to support that?