# cd with double slash hangs forever on Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: bash, osx, cd-command, slash

If I type `cd //` on the Mac OS X Terminal (Version 2.6.1 (361.1)), the prompt hangs forever. Why?

Curiously that doesn't happen if I do `cd /` or `cd ///`.

I am using El Captain with the bash that comes by default, that is GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/3929

Comment: and related to http://superuser.com/questions/401593/why-is-there-a-directory

Comment: What shell? Neither the default ZSH nor the default bash hang on a `cd //` for me.

Comment: @thrig read the last line of my post :)

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar

Comment: I've been on systems long ago that used the syntax //host/path/etc for hierarchies that were remote-mounted (with NFS, iirc), from another machine. Sounds like the OP was triggering an endless wait for a non-existent remote share.