# What does dot forward slash forward slash mean (.//)?

Tags: command-line, find, filenames, slash

I was querrying a server using a command like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name 'filename"
```

I got many files starting with

```
.//library
```

or

```
.//user
```

What do these things mean?

Comment: Despite what the answers below seem to be claiming, that is *not* the behavior that POSIX specifies for `find`; rather, POSIX specifies that `find` should only add `/` if the argument doesn't already end in one. (You can see this in the quotation in Thomas Dickey's answer, which he seems to have misinterpreted.) Testing on a version of `find` I have handy (`find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`), I find that it conforms to the POSIX specification; that is, that it does *not* insert an extra `/`. Can you post the output of `find --version`?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of `find ./ -type f -name library | od`? I'm wondering if you have some sort of invisible character between the two `/`-s.

Comment: Its a private server and not mine :|

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't mean much: the pattern that you gave `find` was **`./`**, and it is simple for `find` to glue its results onto that path.  A double-slash is ignored (treated as a single slash) except that a *leading* double-slash could have some meaning for some systems.  More important, portable programs assume this behavior.

However, you will see this particular behavior only for BSD-derived systems with an old version of `find` (OSX for example).  NetBSD attempted to fix this in their source in [2005](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/gen/fts.c?rev=1.29&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN); the userland for OSX is **older**.

Checking "recent" FreeBSD, NetBSD and OpenBSD, none produce this behavior.  Linux and Unix (AIX, HPUX, Solaris) likewise do not.

Further reading:

- [Mac Terminal “find” command : What does a double slash in the result output mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249313/mac-terminal-find-command-what-does-a-double-slash-in-the-result-output-mean)
- [pgsql: Remove trailing slashes from directories in find command](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1Zd7Yi-0005p9-BD@gemulon.postgresql.org)
- [find - find files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (POSIX)

  > The **`find`** utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from each file specified by path, evaluating a Boolean expression composed of the primaries described in the OPERANDS section for each file encountered. Each path operand shall be evaluated **unaltered** as it was provided, including all trailing *`<slash>`* characters; all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a *`<slash>`* if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. The relative portion shall contain no dot or dot-dot components, no trailing *`<slash>`* characters, and only single  characters between pathname components.
- [How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username)
- [On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar)

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497/117549

Comment: Note that your quotation doesn't actually agree with the behavior the OP is seeing; it specifies that `find` should only add an extra `/` if the argument didn't already end with one.

Answer (score 6):

The `.//` means current directory, so `.//user` in the output indicates file `user` in the current working directory.

The double `//` should resolve to a single `/`, this is true for all systems I've used. Although, POSIX only defines this behavior only for `///` (or more), and of course `/`.

The double `//` appears because you've used the search path for `find` as `./`, instead of the typical `.`. Both indicates current working directory, and both are correct. This is `find`'s behavior to append the path in that manner in case of relative paths. Note that, this specific behavior of `find` is prevalent in only a subset of systems as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316616/68757) mentioned, and you one is presumably one of them.

Answer (score 2):

`.//` is the same as `./`

Successive slashes beyond the first have no semantic meaning.