# Difference between `/` and `//` directories

Tags: bash, directory

Due to a typo, I accidentally `cd` into `//`. Which turns out to be a real directory (but same content as `/`)

So what is the difference between `/` and `//` (despite having identical content)

---

Real example: (`ls` output shortened for brevity)

```
:/$ cd /
:/$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc ...
:/$ cd //
://$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc ...
://$ cd //////// 
:/$ ls (notice how it entered `/` and not `//`)
bin  boot  dev  etc ...
:/$
```

So from the test above it seems that `//` is a special directory. This appears to be only bash, zsh did not have this quirk. Also `//etc`, `//var`, etc; all appear to be valid

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar

Answer (score 0):

You are cd'ing into the same dir. Multiple slashes are ignored.

```
cd /
```

will take you to the same (in this case root) dir as

```
cd //
```

or

```
cd //////
```

Comment: ["A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)

Comment: yes, but you would have to set that up beforehand. The OP asked about "cd"