# Difference between ls command options:`ls -a` `ls -al` `ls -all`

Tags: linux, ls

First look at the output of `ls --help` command:

**Several lines ignored in the output**

```
-a, --all                  do not ignore entries starting with .
-l                         use a long listing format
```

1. As you can see **`-a`** and **`-all`** should be same
2. I found **`-l`** flag but there is no **`-al`** in the help but this flag works

---

So **my questions** are:

1. Why don't **`-a`** and **`-all`** return the same output but help shows both of them in a same line?
2. Is **`-al`** an old form of **`-all`** because both are the same but I didn't find manual for **`-al`**
3. What's the meaning of **`.  ..`** in the **`ls -a`** output?

***Outputs of above commands included below:***

**`ls -a :`**

```
.  ..  article.png  bgame  newtest
```

**`ls -all :`**

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 shahab shahab  4096 Sep 19 12:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 33 shahab sudo    4096 Oct 28 16:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 shahab shahab 15504 Aug 19 16:06 article.png
drwxr-xr-x  5 shahab shahab  4096 Aug 19 10:41 bgame
drwxr-xr-x  5 shahab shahab  4096 Aug 29 16:48 newtest
```

**`ls -al :`**

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 shahab shahab  4096 Sep 19 12:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 33 shahab sudo    4096 Oct 28 16:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 shahab shahab 15504 Aug 19 16:06 article.png
drwxr-xr-x  5 shahab shahab  4096 Aug 19 10:41 bgame
drwxr-xr-x  5 shahab shahab  4096 Aug 29 16:48 newtest
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re missing the extra hyphen: `ls -a` is the same as `ls --all`, with two hyphens.

`ls -all`, with a single hyphen, is the same as `ls -a -l -l`, which is the same as `ls -a -l`, which is the same as `ls -al`.

A single `-` introduces short options, which are single characters, and can be combined. Two `-`s introduce long options, which are words (or multiple words) and can’t be combined.

In the `ls -a` output, `.` represents the current directory, and `..` represents the parent directory.

Comment: tnx in advance sir. so one more question is whats the meaning of add a same flag **`-l`** 3 times? of course each time you copy-paste this flag it wont add more details on output because as you said **`ls -a -l -l`** same as **`ls -a -l`** also am I understood true that, you can combine two flags by type one hyphen and then both flags? .e.g **`-a`** + **`-b`** = **`-ab`** ?? (thanks again)

Comment: sorry, since I'm a beginner, I love learning by asking! 2nd question is:  are there 2 files in every directory, one for current directory **`.`** one for parent directory **`..`**
what are they using for?

Comment: Adding `-l` more than once doesn’t make any difference (unlike other programs where some options increase their effect if they’re added more than once). Two flags can indeed be combined, `-a` and `-b` becomes `-ab`.

Comment: really thanks for this **best answering**

Comment: Yes, each directory in a POSIX file system contains `.` and `..`. To understand `..`, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541779/86440) and its answers, and the linked questions. `.` provides a reference to the current directory in a generic way.